# Winform Treeview find node by tag

Tags: c#, winforms, search, treeview

I have a treeview where the display member could possibly have duplicates, and the tag would not. Example:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(itemName);
node.Tag = itemID; //unique ID for the item
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
```

So, when searching, I know I can search by the itemName by using

```
treeView1.Nodes.Find(itemName, true);
```

But how could I go about searching via the tag? There's no definition for treeView1.Nodes.Where, so no linq for me :(

Any suggestions on how to search by the tag? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = treeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(node=>node.Tag.Equals(itemID));
```

**NOTE**: Because you said your `itemID` is unique, so you can use `FirstOrDefault` to search for the unique item. If it's not found the `result` will be `null`.

### UPDATE

To search for all the nodes at all levels, you can try using some recursive method, like this:

```
public TreeNode FromID(string itemId, TreeNode rootNode){
   foreach(TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes){
     if(node.Tag.Equals(itemId)) return node;
     TreeNode next = FromID(itemId, node);
     if(next != null) return next;
   }
   return null;
}
//Usage    
TreeNode itemNode = null;
foreach(TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes){
  itemNode = FromID(itemId, node);
  if(itemNode != null) break;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you much! (I can't select you as the answer for 3 more minutes, but I will)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get this to work with child nodes as well? I will have multiple generations of nodes, and currently can only search the top level.

Comment: Woo! You're awesome. :) I'd double vote if I could. haha Thank you!

Comment: @user1548103 I can't see his answer to your question about child nodes :( Can you tell me how can I find in all levels of childs ?

Comment: @Andrew each `foreach` in `FromID` is a level, the `rootNode.Nodes` is the code to access to the childNodes. Then we recursively call `FromID` in the foreach to go to the deeper (next) level. This way using recursion approach, which is in fact much easier to understand than using a `Stack`.

Answer (score 3):

The Name property is probably a better answer for this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.name(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var itemNode = new TreeNode(itemName);
itemNode.Name = itemID.ToString();
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

var insertedNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find(itemID.ToString(), true);
```

I would say this is a much cleaner way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public TreeNode GetNode(string name, TreeNode rootNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals(name)) return node;
            TreeNode next = GetNode(name, node);
            if (next != null) return next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public TreeNode GetNode(string name)
    {
        TreeNode itemNode = null;
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeViewPermission.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals(name)) return node;
            itemNode = GetNode(name, node);
            if (itemNode != null) break;
        }
        return itemNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By Tag version of @Hamix's

```
        public TreeNode GetNode(object tag, TreeNode rootNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Tag.Equals(tag)) return node;

                //recursion
                var next = GetNode(tag, node);
                if (next != null) return next;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public TreeNode GetNode(object tag)
        {
            TreeNode itemNode = null;
            foreach (TreeNode node in _sourceTreeView.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Tag.Equals(tag)) return node;

                itemNode = GetNode(tag, node);
                if (itemNode != null) break;
            }
            return itemNode;
        }
```