# For each Node in TreeList

Tags: c#, foreach, treelist

I'm having some logic problems. I have a dictionary on my form where I keep it the name of the node and the value it carries.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> documents = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> doc1 in documents)
    {
        foreach (TreeListNode node in treeList1.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Checked == true)
            {
                Memo.Lines.add("Checked");
            }
            else
            {
                Memo.Lines.add("Not Checked");
            }
        }

        Memo.Lines.add(doc1.value, GetNodeName(doc1.Key));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you run the command, he is making a loop regarding the amount of node in treelist. I am not able to get the code to run only once ...

For each item in the dictionary it should check whether the node is checked and execute the command, it does not run another command. And at the end of the first loop executes a command.

**NOTE: My node in treelist is with the option to show checkbox**

Comment: What do you mean by `name`?  `TreeListNode` does not have a name property.  Do you mean `Tag`?  If so, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226857/winform-treeview-find-node-by-tag) for how to get the node with the corresponding `Tag`

Comment: It is a variable that takes the name of the node (node.GetDisplayText). I created this way it is easy masi in my case

Comment: Use the same method in the linked answer I supplied, but replace your lambda with something like `node=>node.GetDisplayText().Equals(doc1.Key)`