# How to find a Treenode and set Checked=True

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, find, treeview, treenode

I am trying to use the `Find` method to find a node in a `TreeView` and then set the `CheckBox` of that node to `True`.

```
Dim node As TreeNode() = TreeView1.Nodes.Find(FindStr, True)
```

The code finds the node fine, but when I try something like

```
TreeView1.Nodes(node).Checked=True
```

it's not having any of it, node isn't returning an `Integer`. I presume it is returning a collection of what it's found, which is fine. Since the keys are unique it is only going to return the one node, if it does find it. But I'm still not having any luck being able to check its box.

I've been googling for an answer for well over an hour, trying varying keywords just in case but I'm not getting any useful results back.

Answer (score 2):

The `Find`-function returns an Array of nodes.

If the first found node should be checked, the following will work:

```
Dim nodes As TreeNode() = TreeView1.Nodes.Find(FindStr, True)

'Check if at least one node was found
If nodes.Length > 0 Then
    'Set Checked=True for the first found node (index 0)
    nodes(0).Checked = True
End If
```

Comment: ahhh! my next problem is I have been storing my unique ID under the tag (a database record ID) - and I think the find is looking for the fullpath - would I be right in assuming that? (fullpath being the text representation of the nodes)

Comment: Yes, it's looking for the text. If you need to search for tag, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226857/winform-treeview-find-node-by-tag

Comment: that was really helpful, I like the look of the one liner (linq? I had just finished writing a recursive search loop when you posted) and would prefer to get the one-liner working, converted to vb it was
Dim result = TreeView1.Nodes.OfType(Of TreeNode)().FirstOrDefault(Function(node) node.Tag.Equals(TagName))

(tagname being the var for what im looking for) but it doesnt seem to return anything, result is always null, so just need to find out why that is.

Comment: The LINQ one liner does not work for recursive searching. I doubt that there is a way to solve this with a one liner.

Comment: ah right. Well thank you very much Mat - you have been most helpful, I really appreciate the help :)