# Iterative addition of data to a treeview to n depth

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a branching data structure with a single root which branches *x* number of times (always the same number of times for each level and can be set) and has *n* number of levels (variable). I have the data structure working but i want to output it to a Treeview. I cannot work out how to add this data to the treeview. Each level are children only of the members of the level above them. *n* can be any number. I am holding the data in a list of lists of the data type. so for example if i set the branches to 2 and the levels to 4 I have a list with 4 sub lists the first list contains one item (the root) the second contains 2 children of level 1, the third contains the 4 children of level 2, the 4th contains the 8 children of level 3. Each item in a level is cross referenced up and down so contains the ID and index of a child's parent and of it's own children.

How can i elegantly set up a treeview from this data?.

i've tried using a foreach loop of treeview1.Nodes looking for an ID (set to Node.Name) but it only ever returns the root node and none of it's children.

```
private void ToTree ()
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    TreeNode lead = new TreeNode(Formation[0][0].Name);
    lead.Name = Formation[0][0].ID.ToString();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(lead);
    int a = Formation.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) 
    {
        int b = Formation[i].Count;
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            string c = Formation[i][j].Parent.ToString();
            TreeNode d = new TreeNode(Formation[i][j].Name);
            d.Name = Formation[i][j].ID.ToString();
            foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Name.Equals(c))
                     treeView1.Nodes[node.Index].Nodes.Add(d);
             }
         }
    
     }

}
```

this works to add the children to the root but does not their children or any further down the structure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226857/winform-treeview-find-node-by-tag

This solved my issue.